# Strange issue with SonarQube issues listing

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm facing a strange issue where developers don't see anything when clicking on "Issues" on their project (it was working before and suddenly stopped working). The dashboard shows issues (ie: 11 issues), but when they click on the desired metric, the list is empty. Using the administrator account and my non-administrator account, I'm able to see the issues list.

We are using LDAP authentication with LDAP groups mappings. Security is applied per project using permission templates.

The workaround I've found is to log in as "Administrator", apply the default permission template to the project, and immediately re-apply the proper permission template. That fixes the issue temporarily.

Is it a bug in SonarQube or in the SonarQube LDAP plugin itself?

**SonarQube version**

5.5

**Plugins installed**

- sonar-csharp-plugin-5.0
- sonar-java-plugin-3.13.1
- sonar-javascript-plugin-2.12
- sonar-json-plugin-1.4
- sonar-l10n-fr-plugin-1.13
- sonar-ldap-plugin-1.5.1
- sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2
- sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.3
- sonar-web-plugin-2.4
- sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.1

Comment: You pose this as though it has happened multiple times... on the same project? Once each on multiple projects? Also, what do the permissions look like before you reset them?

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team: It occurred on three projects, all using the same permission template. The permission template contains three Active Directory groups. The developers are member of these groups. I have also tried clearing their groups from the User Management page in SonarQube. When they log in back, the roles are granted again, as expected.

Comment: Any thoughts? It just happened again. All I have to do is apply the Default project permission template and then re-apply the desired permission template.

Comment: You should try to clean up the elastic search indexes : Stop the server, remove the {SQ}/data/es folder, and restart the server.